# Set instance variable twice with "self.variable = value" causes memory leak?

Tags: iphone, memory, variables, sdk, memory-leaks

Until yesterday I thought that I had understood the iPhones memory management.
Well here is my problem:

```
// .h file
     @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dicParams;
     @property(nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary *dicReferences;
     @property(nonatomic, retain) FtMonitorHandler *monitorHandler;

// .m file
@synthesize dicParams, dicReferences, monitorHandler;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.dicReferences = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        self.monitorHandler = [[FtMonitorHandlerService alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [monitorHandler release];
    [dicParams release];
    [dicReferences release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

If I set somewhere else, after the viewcontroller's allocation for example

```
self.dicParams = dicValues;
```

… it will turn into a leak

My understanding of setting instance variables with "self. …" was, that the current value will be "released" and then set with "retain".

I tried a little bit with instruments. Results:

```
-(void)createLeak { 
    self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
    self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
}

-(void)createAnotherLeak { 
    self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
    self.dicParams = nil; 
    self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 
}

- (void)createWithoutLeak { 
    if(dicParams != nil) [dicParams release]; 
    self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
}
```

Have I missed something, or is this the behavior as it should be?

**EDIT: I tried to implement the suggested changes. It works fine, as long, as my variable is not GUI element. (UIView, UILabel, etc)**

The autorelease will cause an app crash after a memory warning

```
- (void)loadView {  
    [super loadView];
    // ... here is some other stuff ...  
    self.lblDeparture = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];  
}  

- (void)viewDidUnload {  
    [super viewDidUnload];  
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.  
    self.lblDeparture = nil;
}

- (void)dealloc {  
    [lblDeparture release];  
    [super dealloc];  
}
```

I'm not quite sure, but I assume that the following lines are the real issue:

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, INFO_VIEW_HEIGHT);  
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];  

[imageView addSubview:lblDeparture];  
[lblDeparture release];  // is this correct?

[self.view addSubview:imageView];  
[imageView release];
```

Comment: why you are using self.yourObjects, you are in same class so rather than retaining it(by calling self.yourObject) you can try without self.

Comment: wouldn't there be a leak if I assign the variable twice with "variable = …", because the first reference will be gone? without "self.variable …"

Comment: no I am saying you should try with dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
 rather than  self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
.

Answer (score 4):

if you init you need to auto release.

```
-(void)dontCreateAnotherLeak {
    self.dicParams = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.dicParams = nil;
    self.dicParams = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

the easier equivalent is to use the convenience accessor.

```
self.dicParams = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
```

if you would like to handle this yourself. On top of the @synthesize dictParams; you will also want to create your own setter.

```
-(void)setDictParams:(NSMutableDictionary*) newDictParams
{
    if (dictParams != newDictParams)
    {
        [dictParams release];
        dictParams = [newDictParams retain];
    }
}
```

this is a little simple. but essentially what the compiler creates with the retain modifier added to the @property tag

Comment: More specifically when you init and pass into a setter that ALSO retains, you need to autorelease...

Comment: Even better - wrap that up as `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tested it and it worked fine. Though i prefer to use it without autorelease and create a temporary variable that i release afterwards

Comment: there is no performance problems with using an autoreleased object. however if you want to do it yourself then you will need to implement your own setDictParams method. Ill add that to my answer.

Comment: and when would the variable be removed from the pool? until now i thought that having control over release on my own is the better way and debugger crashes would be easier to find

Comment: autorelease will perform the real release on the object for each time autorelease was called. This release will be done at the end of the run loop. (e.g. when the application goes back from the message to the queue looking for more messages. it will release these objects)

Comment: Your example of the `setDictParams:` method is wrong. You either need to retain before you release or you need to check if `newDictParams != dictParams` first. Otherwise this will blow up if you call the setter with the current object.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a instance variable for which you have specified `retain` in `property` retain count becomes 1

Now as you call with reference to self as in case “self.variable = value” increase the `retain` count by 1, So the total retain count becomes 2.

So now to release it you need to bring retain count to 0. Hence you need to release it twice.

Hopew this helps.

Comment: would it be a possibility to use @property(assign) instead if I prefer to use "self. …"

Comment: @user707342 : Will not recommend you for assign but you can use below self.myVariable = nil ; before setting it again ....

Comment: Sorry, you probably meant to say the right thing, but what’s actually written here is *wrong*!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand the question fully, however your second part is easily explained...

> -(void)createLeak {
>
> ```
> self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
>
> self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
> ```

that's clear...

now but this one

> -(void)createAnotherLeak {
>
> ```
> self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
>
> self.dicParams = nil;
>
> self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; }
> ```

does not release the first alloced self.dicParams but rather forgets any reference to it by setting it to nil and then resetting it with a new one. Setting to nil is not equal to release. If you would have created the first one with autorelease and then set it to nil it's something different. That should work correctly. And that's exatcly what you do with your 3rd example!

Now as to your inital question, what is it that leaks when you write

> self.dicParams = dicValues;

?

the variable  self.dicParams should just hold the value until you release it again

Comment: i can't say it for sure but instruments marks an other object that has two NSArrays and does the self.lines = [NSArray alloc] init]; My parser later overwrites this array with new values causing the suspected leak.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read Apple's Memory Management Programming Guide carefully. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html

It's all explained in there.

There are a couple of obvious mistakes I can see that you are making.

Firstly, you shouldn't use accessors in `init` or `dealloc`.

So, this

```
- (id)init { 
 self = [super init];

 if (self) {
    self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.dicReferences = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    self.monitorHandler = [[FtMonitorHandlerService alloc] init];
 }
 return self;
}
```

should be

```
- (id)init { 
 self = [super init];

 if (self) {
    dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    dicReferences = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    monitorHandler = [[FtMonitorHandlerService alloc] init];
 }
 return self;
}
```

Secondly, when you set a retained property, the you need to release the whatever you are setting it to.

So, this

```
self.dicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
```

should be

```
self.dicParams = [[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or you can do this

```
NSMutableDictionary *newDicParams = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
self.dicParams = newDicParams;
[newDictParams release];
```

Comment: thanks for your explainations :-) Has you last described method any benefits over the allocation with autorelease in this perspective?

Comment: Releasing manually is preferable to autorelease because it is effective immediately. An autoreleased object gets released when it goes out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

The setter generated by `@synthesize` for a `(readwrite, retain, nonatomic)` property looks something like this:

```
 - (void) setSomething: (id) newSomething;
 {
      if (something != newSomething) {
          [something release];
          something = [newSomething retain];
      }
 }
```

The old object pointed to by the instance variable `something` will be released while the new object will be retained.

Your mistake is the object creation. You create your dictionary with `[[NSDictionary alloc] init]`. This dictionary has a retain count of 1. Your setter retains the object, so the new retain count is 2. When you call the setter again the retain count of your original dictionary correctly gets decreased - it’s 1 again. For the dictionary to be freed you’d have to release it again. For this there is `autorelease`. An autoreleased object will get released some time later. So the correct code to set your property would be

```
 self.something = [[[NSDictionary alloc] init] autorelease];
```

or even better using the convenience allocator

```
 self.something = [NSDictionary dictionary];
```

You really should read and understand Apple’s memory management guide - it’s all explained in there.

By the way, I talked about retain counts here. It’s OK to think about them, but you should never ask an object about it’s retain count, that value is useless, since it’s rarely what you would think.

Comment: Thanks for this your explaination. This will help me a lot :-)